# Make TranslateBehavior and translatable strings work at the same time

Tags: cakephp, translation, locale, cakephp-3.0

- **What I want**

What I want to do is, based on the `Accept-Language` sent by the user's browser, to translate both the in-code strings (`__('translatable string')`) and the fields I have configured from tables that have the `TranslateBehavior`.

- **What I did**

Added

```
DispatcherFactory::add('LocaleSelector', ['locales' => ['en_US', 'el_GR']]);
```

in `bootstrap.php` in order to set the locale automatically, using the `Accept-Language` that is sent by the user's browser. This works just fine and sets the locale to either `en_US` or `el_GR`.

I also have setup i18n (following http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/translate.html) because I want some fields of a table of mine to be translatable.

Of course, I have strings in my code that do not come from the database and need to be translated. I use the `__()` function for that.

- **The problem**

Let's say the user, through `Accept-Language`, requests Greek (`el_GR`), then the locale will be set to `el_GR`. The function `__()` will work out of the box, because it is exactly what it needs.

But, the `TranslateBehavior` will not work, because it needs `gre`, not `el_GR`.

How can I make those 2 work at the same time, while they expect different locale value for the same language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long discussion and help from @ndm, I took the following measures to make it work:

1. After doing the appropriate changes, completely clear your `tmp` directory and update composer. This solved a problem where `LocaleSelector`, while it was setting the appropriate locale, my database wasn't being translated.
2. There is the problem that the `Accept-Language` header can have many values. You want many of them to be matched with a specific locale. That way you will be able to have the same locale for everything, both for your database and translatable strings. In order to solve this problem, I made my own `LocaleSelectorFilter` and I placed it in `src/Routing/Filter`. It overrides the default `LocaleSelectorFilter`:

   namespace Cake\Routing\Filter;

   use Cake\Event\Event;
   use Cake\I18n\I18n;
   use Cake\Routing\DispatcherFilter;
   use Locale;

   class LocaleSelectorFilter extends DispatcherFilter
   {

   ```
   protected $_locales = [];

   public function __construct($config = [])
   {
       parent::__construct($config);
       if (!empty($config['locales'])) {
           $this->_locales = $config['locales'];
       }
   }

   private function matchLocaleWithConfigValue($localeFromHeader)
   {
       foreach ($this->_locales as $locale => $acceptableValues) {
           // $acceptableValues is either an array or a single string
           if (!$locale) {
               // single string
               if ($localeFromHeader === $acceptableValues) {
                   return $acceptableValues;
               }
           } else {
               // array
               foreach ($acceptableValues as $acceptableValue) {
                   if ($localeFromHeader === $acceptableValue) {
                       return $locale;
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       return false;
   }

   public function beforeDispatch(Event $event)
   {
       $request = $event->data['request'];
       $locale = Locale::acceptFromHttp($request->header('Accept-Language'));

       if (!$locale) {
           // no locale set in the headers
           return;
       }

       if (empty($this->_locales)) {
           // any locale value allowed
           I18n::locale($locale);
           return;
       }

       // search whether the requested language is in the accepted ones
       $localeConfigMatch = $this->matchLocaleWithConfigValue($locale);

       if (!$localeConfigMatch) {
           // no locale matches the header, leave the default one
           return;
       }

       // match was found, switch locale
       I18n::locale($localeConfigMatch);
   }
   ```

   }

It is used like this, inside `bootstrap.php`:

```
DispatcherFactory::add('LocaleSelector', ['locales' => ['el_GR' => ['el', 'el_GR', 'el-GR'], 'en_US']]);
```

In the above example, all the values `el`, `el_GR` and `el-GR` of the `Accept-Language` will result to the locale `el_GR` being set. Also, if `Accept-Language` has the `en_US` value, it will be set. So it supports both many different values to be set to one specific locale and it also supports the default `LocaleSelector` behavior.

3. Your `i18n` table's locale column must be set to 'el_GR' (in this example). This is necessary, because it is what the in-code translatable strings expect (the ones using the `__()` function). So by setting 'el_GR' (instead of 'gre', mentioned in the documentation) you will have both the in-code translatable strings and database translatable fields work out of the box.

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

The Translate Behavior doesn't impose any restrictions on the locale identifier format. The possible values are only limited by the database column type/length.

So, just use `en_US` and `el_GR` for your translation table records and you should be good.

Comment: Nope, I tried that, it doesn't work. In my `i18n` table I've set the locale to `el_GR` everywhere. Launching from a browser requesting `el_GR` still returns the english translations. And yes, I checked and `I18n::locale()` correctly returns `el_GR`, so no, it doesn't work.

Comment: @hakermania It works just fine, I have the Locale Selector and the Translate Behavior in use exactly like that, using `xx_XX` identifiers. If your records really have `el_GR` set in the `locale` column, then you need to debug your code further, like check that the local is being prorperly set by the behavior, check the issued queries, etc.

Comment: something fishy is going on. It worked. Once. When I manually set the locale to el_GR it worked only once.

Comment: If I disable the `LocaleSelector` and I manually set the locale, it works in any case. The translation takes into account something else apart from the string value of the locale

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me sorting it out. I made a final answer describing all the steps